# stopping sap from coming through prime/sealed and painted wood

Tags: finishing

My contractor installed new ledges on my porch.  He primed them twice with a sealer/primer and then painted two coats of high gloss trim paint.  Now, I have spots and cracks where sap is seeping through and making a mess of the whole area.  If I sand it to rough it up, then use shelak can I then paint the high gloss paint over that and the sap won't come through again?

Comment: I did a little research on this, and really found little. The most I could find was if you have a sappy board there is 2 good options I thought would work. You can use shelak I have read but it could wreck the finish. The other was to just replace the wood. Which for you does not seem piratical.  My personal thought was just let it, and when it stops then I would go ahead and sand and just refinish. Otherwise I hope somebody on this group knows better than me. Related topic on woodworking. https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/what-are-the-techniques-to-seal-or-remove-sap

Comment: Paint with a two part epoxy paint. The sap cannot penetrate through the crosslinked epoxide bonds.